# change font size on gnuplot

Tags: fonts, gnuplot

I know there have been several posts on how to change the font size on gnuplot. However, in my code, even though I take the solution in previous posts, the output figures have no change. My code is :

```
set terminal png size 1280, 480;
set xrange [0:100]
set yrange [0:1]
set xlabel 'n'
set ylabel 'x_n'
set tics font ",1"
set output './time_series/r'.i.'.'.j.''.k.''.l.'.png';
set title 'r = '.i.'.'.j.''.k.''.l;

do for [i=0:3]{
    do for [j=0:9]{
    do for [k=0:9]{
    do for [l=0:9]{
    plot './time_series/r'.i.'.'.j.''.k.''.l.'.txt' every ::0::100 with linespoints ls 1 ps 1 pt 7 notitle
    }
    }
    }
}
```

The command has no effect with any number I put into, i.e.

```
set tics font ",a number"
```

Any number produces the same font. Is there anything I missed?

Thank you everyone.

Update :
Thanks Raphael. Here are two png produced. The first is with [set tics font ",1"]. The second, [set tics font ",10"].
[image]
[image]

Comment: cannot reproduce your issue, set tics font works fine for me (gnuplot 5)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**AD1:** the correct way to set tics font size is

```
set tics font "name{,<size>}"
```

eg.

```
set tics font "Helvetica,10"
```

**AD2**: set tics font resizes only the fonts of x-y axes. To resize all the fonts (eg. the `title`) use

```
set terminal png size 1280, 480 font "Helvetica,30"
```

(or any other fontname and/or size :o) )

Answer (score 0):

To change fonts locally/inline, one can use (from the ps_guide.pdf of gnuplot):
[image]

```
{/Helvetica m}      # font change
{/Helvetica=18 m}   # font and size change
{/=8 m}             # size change
{/*2 m}             # relative size scaling
```